# Error java.lang.NullPointerException en Glassfish 5.0

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

tengo un problema con mi web aplication creado en java, cuando lo corro en netbeans, el navegador se abre y sale el siguiente error:

```
URL:http://localhost:8080/ControlClientes/ServletControlador

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Solo tengo essta excepcion y no se como arreglarlo, pero, pienso que tiene que ver con el `ServletControlador.java`.

Ademas, me comentaron que seria util publicar el error que se produce en consola de netbeans, que es el siguiente:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id_cliente' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:122)
    at datos.ClienteDaoJDBC.listar(ClienteDaoJDBC.java:32)
    at web.ServletControlador.doGet(ServletControlador.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
  StandardWrapperValve[web.ServletControlador]: Servlet.service() for servlet web.ServletControlador threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at datos.Conexion.close(Conexion.java:27)
    at datos.ClienteDaoJDBC.listar(ClienteDaoJDBC.java:47)
    at web.ServletControlador.doGet(ServletControlador.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**ServletControlador.java**

```
package web;

import datos.ClienteDaoJDBC;
import dominio.Cliente;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/ServletControlador")
public class ServletControlador extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
        
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ClienteDaoJDBC().listar();
        System.out.println("clientes = " + clientes);
        request.setAttribute("clientes", clientes);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("clientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**clientes.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Control de clientes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Control de clientes</h1>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="cliente" items="${clientes}">
                
                <li>${cliente.idCliente} ${cliente.nombre} ${cliente.apellido} 
                    ${cliente.saldo}</li>
                
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ServletControlador">
```

**ClienteDaoJDBC.java**

```
package datos;

import dominio.Cliente;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClienteDaoJDBC {

    private static final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT id_cliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo"
            + "FROM cliente";

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_BY_ID = "SELECT id_cliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo"
            + "FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = ?";

    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO cliente(nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo)"
            + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE cliente"
            + "SET nombre=?, apellido=?, email=?, telefono=?, saldo=? WHERE id_cliente=?";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = ?";

    public List<Cliente> listar() {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Cliente cliente = null;
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            conn = Conexion.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int idCliente = rs.getInt("id_cliente");
                String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                String apellido = rs.getString("apellido");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String telefono = rs.getString("telefono");
                double saldo = rs.getDouble("saldo");

                cliente = new Cliente(idCliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo);
                clientes.add(cliente);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            Conexion.close(rs);
            Conexion.close(stmt);
            Conexion.close(conn);
        }
        return clientes;
    }
}
```

Me falta mencionar que tengo dos entradas o registros en mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leido sobre el error `java.lang.NullPointerException`  pero, no se cual variable o objeto tiene el valor de`nulo`,el web aplication tiene mas `.java` pero no vi la necesidad de agregarlos porque creo que ahi no esta el poblema.

Gracias por leer mi pregunta y espero que exista una solucion.

Comment: En la consola de netbeans deberías poder ver exactamente en qué línea está el error ese, y con eso, saber exactamente qué variable es. El error que se muestra en el html no da mucha ayuda... De todas maneras, te recomiendo que aprendas a usar el *debugger* de netbeans, es realmente útil para estas cosas!

Comment: Sería mejor que colocarás toda la excepción que te muestre la consola de NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no estoy 100% seguro, yo probaría añadiendo el espacio que falta en tu consulta

Tienes

```
private static final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT id_cliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo"
            + "FROM cliente";
```

y ahí falta un espacio antes del FROM. Si hicieras debug, tu consulta estaría mal formada. Debería ser:

```
private static final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT id_cliente, nombre, apellido, email, telefono, saldo"
            + " FROM cliente";
```

con un espacio entre `saldo` y `FROM`.

Si ese es el problema, revisaría en las demás consultas.

Comment: Correcto, prece ser un muy mal error asumir el error de sintaxys asi por parte del manejador de conexiones de MySQL, pero en efecto es el espacio en el form

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la conexion a la base de datos esta mal, por que falla al intentar ejecutar el query, literalmente el stack trace dice que no existe la columna id_cliente aqui:

```
Unknown column 'id_cliente' in 'field list'
```

Puede ser que la base que tengas como referencia sea incorrecta, pero el error es de la consulta q que ejecutas solo que hace efecto burbuja hacia arriba y pareciese ser del WebServlet

Comment: Cuando la conexión falla, el error es otro. Aquí esta validando los campos de la consulta.

Comment: Jamas dije que la conexion fallara, explicitamente dije que es probable que sea otro error referente a la conexion por que no detecta las columnas